# Finding a vector given the length and another vector in the same direction

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

Given the length of a vector $\|v\| = 2$, and the same direction as $u = (\sqrt{3},3,0)$.

How to calculate vector $v$?

I thought I needed to use the formula for a unit vector:
u= v/\|v\|
v = (2(sqrt{3},6,0) which is wrong

Comment: Where is your attempt?

Comment: Hi, welcome to math.SE! You can make $\sqrt{3}$ and other mathematical symbols using MathJax, see a tutorial [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). Also, you are expected to show what you've already attempted to solve this problem. You can edit your question to include this.

Answer (score 0):

[Normalize](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NormalizedVector.html) the vector $\vec u$ and then [multiply by two](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalar_multiplication).